# Word or phrase to say you're not taking advantage of an opportunity

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

I was about to write something along the lines of

> the advantage of having a swimming pool nearby wasn't spent on me,

but is that even correct?

What would be a good alternative?

Comment: Why would you call it an advantage if it wasn't?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, presumably having a pool nearby is an advantage to most people and would be seen as so by a reader, but the questioner merely hasn't taken advantage of the advantage (if that makes any sense)

Comment: "I was unaffected by the advantage..." or 'the advantage... did not affect me".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can I say, *"the advantages of having a swimming pool nearby **missed out on me***"?

Comment: @NVZ that doesn't make sense to me. I'd go with "*I missed out on the advantages of have a swimming pool nearby.*". However *wasted* makes more sense all-round.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey "Of *having* a swimming pool"

Comment: @MorganFR I know, I only noticed the mistake when I could no longer edit my comment. :,-(

Comment: @NVZ: No. But you can certainly say, for example, *I **missed out on** the benefit*, or *The advantage **was lost on** me*.

Comment: Please do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). They are out of scope and your question may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about **wasted**? As per [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wasted):

> not used, spent, etc., in a good, useful, or effective way

Works well in your example:

> The advantage of having a swimming pool nearby **was wasted** on me

Comment: +1. You may reformulate: "I wasted the advantage of having a swimming pool nearby.

Comment: It even fits in the phrase ["wasted on"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wasted-on-sb).

Answer (score 24):

[**Squander**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squander) — to lose (as an advantage or opportunity) through negligence or inaction

> He vowed not to squander this opportunity.  (Merriam-Webster)

Or, with your example:

> The advantage of having a swimming pool nearby was **squandered** on me.

> I **squandered** the advantage of having a swimming pool nearby.

Comment: [Squander vs waste an opportunity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=squandered+the+opportunity%2Csquandered+an+opportunity%2Cwasted+the+opportunity%2Cwasted+an+opportunity&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csquandered%20the%20opportunity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csquandered%20an%20opportunity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwasted%20the%20opportunity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwasted%20an%20opportunity%3B%2Cc0) Ngrams

Answer (score 11):

*"I **missed out** on the advantages of having a swimming pool nearby."*
*"The advantages ... was **lost** on me."* <sub><sup>Thanks to @FumbleFingers</sup></sub>

**Miss out** (on something) or **lose out** (on something) — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/miss+out)

> To fail to use or enjoy an opportunity.
>
> *"Other people my age are married and have families, and I am beginning to feel I am missing out."*
>   *"We missed out on a chance to get a cheaper mortgage."*

Answer (score 6):

**Miss the boat** — [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/miss-the-boat)
​

> to lose an opportunity to do something by being slow to act.
>
> *"There were tickets available last week, but he missed the boat by waiting till today to try to buy some."*

Comment: How would this work in the example sentence though? It would probably get confusing with *boat* and *swimming pool*.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I just thought it'd be a relevant idiom. Didn't actually try fitting it to the given sentence.

Comment: well in that case I completely agree with you, it is a related idiom, however, fitting it into the sentence would be most helpful for the OP

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Suggestions welcome. How to best tailor this idiom to meet OP's requirements?

Comment: *I've missed the boat in regards to the advantages of having a swimming pool nearby* vaguely fits, but as I say it doesn't fit fantastically.

Comment: To me, this idiom implies a timeline where an event has occurred, and the opportunity is lost. The OP implies an unnoticed situation, which hasn't necessarily changed. Subtle (and I'm not sure I've expressed it well).

Answer (score 3):

The question is unclear. Was there a swimming pool nearby or not?

If not:

> I wasn't **given the advantage** of a nearby swimming pool.

If so:

> There was a swimming pool nearby, but I didn't **take advantage of it**.

---

From the question:

> ... the advantage of having a swimming pool nearby wasn't spent on me ...

You don't **spend** advantages. You might **make use of** them, or **waste** them.

Answer (score 2):

The verb *to pass* can sometimes be used with this meaning.

> I passed on the available pool.

Answer (score 1):

> Stupidly I **spurned** the opportunity to use the nearby swimming pool.

**to spurn**

> : to refuse to accept (someone or something that you do not think deserves your respect, attention, affection, etc.) 
>   - [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spurn)

Answer (score 1):

***forgo/forego***

From [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/forgo):

> **forgo**
> *(also forego) VERB (forgoes, forgoing, forwent; past participle forgone) [WITH OBJECT]*
>
> **1** **Go without** (*something desirable*):
>
> she wanted to forgo the tea and leave while they could
>
> More example sentences:
>
> Whenever possible, forego fashion and stick with ‘sensible’ shoes.
>
> I may be forced to go and purchase a second bag and forgo tea.
>
> If this is not your cup of tea, forgo the invitation and book a nearby
> hotel room.

I ***forwent*** the advantage of having a swimming pool nearby.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could rephrase it is to review the writing before this sentence.  If those lines make it clear to a reader that having a swimming pool would have been an advantage for you, then instead of repeating the work you've already done, you could do something like "The worst part of the situation?  I had a pool right next door.  I never once jumped in."

Answer (score -1):

*exploited*, as in, "*X* was not something I *"exploited"*.

A better word: *'avail'*, (but requires modifying sentence structure)

*advantage* is the word on which you are operating not *pool*.
specification, say, of the *advantage* being as such, an advantage, would then include pool-related details *in relation* to an aspect personal..; *ex.gr.*: if you are a swimmer now, but did not use an otherwise valuable resource; if you wish you could now jump in a pool but in the past did not avail yourself to the pooliness that had, only in the past, been available.

Perhaps "avail" might be better usage.